# Add more than one arguments when launch a process c#

Tags: c#, vnc

Hy,

I need to launch a vnc viewer in a winform (ultravnc in my case) and I need to send two parameters to see the remote desktop and after several issues, I can't find any solutions.

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/uvnc bvba/ultravnc/vncviewer.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = host;
        proc.Start();
```

the first argument "host" is the ip of the pc and that just work.
After that, ultravnc ask me the password for the remote desktop connection.

And this is where I can't find any solutions :

1)I try to add a second arguments :
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = mdpVNC;
But VNC take this as a replacement of the "host" variable.

2)I try to use the SendKeys class but it doesn't work

3)I try the property "PasswordInClearText" but that doesn't work either.

I try several things and I don't want to use an external package (like vncSharp or other, because these solutions don't suit me)

I need help plz.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arguments are a replacement for user input *only if that's how the target program has been specifically written to behave*. They're not interchangable.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [UltraVNC Viewer documentation page for Command Line Parameters](https://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-viewer/52-UltraVNC-viewer-commandline-parameters.html)?

Comment: `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = host + " -password bla"`;

Answer (score 0):

`StartInfo.Arguments` is a `string`, and you put in there the argument**s**. Make the `string` that has the argument**s** as you would write them in the command line. For example:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "host -dsmplugin msrc4plugin.dsm";
```

*That is for the first example in [UltraVNC Viewer Commandline Parameters](https://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-viewer/52-UltraVNC-viewer-commandline-parameters.html)
.*

Or whatever you need.